# How can I extract a specific part with grep in Linux between multiple double quotes?

Tags: linux, grep, syslog

I would like to extract the part

```
msg="services.facebook.com:Content Server, Rule_name:WAN6_Ongoing, SSI:N (Content)"
```

from

```
src="192.168.1.1:443" dst="192.168.1.1:80" msg="services.facebook.com:Content Server, Rule_name:WAN6_Ongoing, SSI:N (Content)" note="WEB FORWARD" user="unknown" devID="ptz6e398b4a2" cat="Forward Web Sites"
```

When I enter `grep -Eo 'msg=".*"'` it copies me

```
msg="services.facebook.com:Content Server, Rule_name:WAN6_Ongoing, SSI:N (Content)" note="WEB FORWARD" user="unknown" devID="ptz6e398b4a2" cat="Forward Web Sites"
```

I was able to extract the src and dst parts with `grep -Eo 'src="[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,10}"'`

I also want to extract the note, user, and cat parts to put everything in a csv data file. I didn't do it with `awk` $ because the spaces between the words aren't the same every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -Eo '(msg|note|user|cat)="[^"]*"' input_file
msg="services.facebook.com:Content Server, Rule_name:WAN6_Ongoing, SSI:N (Content)"
note="WEB FORWARD"
user="unknown"
cat="Forward Web Sites"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -o 'msg="[^"]*"' file
msg="services.facebook.com:Content Server, Rule_name:WAN6_Ongoing, SSI:N (Content)"

$ grep -o 'src="[^"]*"' file
src="192.168.1.1:443"

$ grep -o 'dst="[^"]*"' file
dst="192.168.1.1:80"
```

The above assumes you don't have any `"`s inside the quoted strings and you don't have tags like `foomsg="..."` where `msg` is a substring.